# Get content of news posts using REST api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sitepages, sharepoint-news

The goal is to use REST to pull content into a homegrown mobile app. I'm able to run simple API calls like this and get results:

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=Title
```

But I can't figure out how to get the full content of news posts, which I believe is in a container named "CanvasContent" i.e title, author byline, first published date, body content, banner image thumbnail, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already tried @ganesh sanap's suggestion but it doesn't get the body content. Figured it out though - needed to add CanvasContent1 in the query so this works:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items?$select=Title,CanvasContent1,FileLeafRef
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the rest with this end point:

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items
```

This will provide you with results of all information.

Comment: See my answer...